# Importing Processed CSV file into Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have been given the following CSV file to be imported into Pandas DataFrame

```
,,,,Facet,Facet,Facet,Facet,Value,Value,Value,Value
Snipit,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Grainy,,,,0,0,1,2,0,0,1,2
Arroyo,Position,Chunk,Grade,,,,,,,,
0,0,0,5,2.0,2.0,2.0,0.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,1.2
0,0,0,21,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,2.0
```

The table is multi indexed by Arroyo', 'Position', 'Chunk', 'Grade and columns
None, 'Snipit', 'Grainy', 'Tiny' saved to to a CSV file.

When attempt to use pd.read_csv I get the following:

```
Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3  Facet   Facet.1     Facet.2     Facet.3     Value   Value.1 Value.2 Value.3
0   Snipit              NaN         NaN        NaN  0.0     0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
1   Grainy              NaN         NaN        NaN  0.0     0.0         1.0         2.0         0.0     0.0     1.0     2.0
2   Tiny                NaN         NaN        NaN  0.0     1.0         0.0         2.0         0.0     1.0     0.0     2.0
3   Arroyo      Position    Chunk       Grade       NaN     NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
4   0                   0       0       5           2.0     2.0         2.0         0.0         2.0     2.0     2.0     1.2
5   0                   0       0       21          0.0     0.0         0.0         2.0         1.0     1.0     1.0     2.0
```

Desired Output

```
                                    Facet   Facet   Facet   Facet   Value   Value   Value   Value
Snipit                              0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
Grainy                              0       0       1       2       0       0       1       2
Tiny                                0       1       0       2       0       1       0       2
Arroyo  Position    Chunk   Grade
0       0           0       5       2.0     2.0     2.0     0.0     2.0     2.0     2.0     1.2
0       0           0       21      0.0     0.0     0.0     2.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     2.0
```

I know that I need to define my index and columns but the only examples I could find where those that were useing flat files. In my case I am dealing with processed data and could not find an example of that.

The question that I have can I import such a file into a pandas DataFrame? From what read I could not see anything

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set multi-index with `index_col` parameter in `read_csv()`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=[0,1,2,3])
```

Comment: Yes Dmitry I know that but with data given to me it is not organized that way the information is in a mixture or columns and rows. Thanks for responding